# iphone - 3 view controllers how to return to first one

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

I have a game with menu - level select - game vc

I'd like to dump the user out to the menu after the game, but I'm doing presentModalViewController's and if I keep a reference to level select VC in my game VC I can dismiss it, but then we see the level select screen for a split second before going back to the menu... ( no animations )

Is there another way to do this? All I know is having a top bar ( navigationController? ) which I don't want showing and this presentModal way I'm currently using to switch view controllers.

How I dismiss the game view controller:

```
- (void)dismissMe {
    NSLog(@"dismissMe");
    [mParentVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
//    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the rootViewController on the UIWindow object.

[[UIApplication] sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = theVCYouWantDisplayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use UINavigationController with navigationBarHidden property set to YES

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks for the idea.